# Delay fadein and fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a list of objects and iterate over fading them in and out. However, every time the page loads, it jumps to the 'Last Text'. I assume it's doing something asynchronous and has just flashed through the list because the console prints out all of the values. Every solution I've found ends up with the same result.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var resumation = [
    {value: "First Text", type: "text", top: 340, duration: 5},
    {value: "Second Text", type: "text", top: 340, duration: 5},
    {value: "Last Text", type: "text", top: 340, duration: 5}
  ];
  $("#ab-text").fadeOut(0);
  $.each(resumation, function(index, obj){
    console.log(obj.value);
    $("#ab-text").empty().append(obj.value).fadeIn(5000, function(){
      $("#ab-text").delay(3000).fadeOut(5000, function(){
        return;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ab-text"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The isse with your code is that `$.each` doesn't wait for nothing. It loops through all elements at once, as you should see in the console with your `.log` statement. This means that `ab-text` will be set to all the different values almost immediately, stopping at the last item.

You must somehow invoke the animation of the next element *after* the animation is complete. So you thought the right thing, but forgot about the `each` .

Something like this works out better, by recursively calling the `next` function after each animation is complete.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var resumation = [
    {value: "First Text", type: "text", top: 340, duration: 5},
    {value: "Second Text", type: "text", top: 340, duration: 5},
    {value: "Last Text", type: "text", top: 340, duration: 5}
  ];

  next(0);

  function next (i) {
    var obj = resumation[i % resumation.length];
    $("#ab-text").empty().append(obj.value).fadeIn(5000, function () {
      $("#ab-text").delay(3000).fadeOut(5000, function(){
        next(i + 1);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ab-text"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution.